# variable name of table in select query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I would like to add into my query name of table from my string variable **tablename**. Is it possible in c#? I tried something like below. But it doesn't work. As you can see i want to set the **FROM @tablename** on **scores**

```
public void tableInsertTest()
        {

            MySqlConnection conn = null;

            string tablename = "scores";

            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
                conn.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 90;
                cmd.CommandText = (

                "INSERT INTO dailyrecords(recorddate, firstname, lastname, score ) " +
                "SELECT NOW(), name, lname, score FROM @tablename " );

                cmd.Prepare();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tablename);

                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                conn.Close();

            }

            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Generally, database libraries don't let you use parameters for object names, only values. You'll need to manually insert the table name in this case it seems.

Comment: I've edited your question, see why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO dailyrecords(recorddate, firstname, lastname, score ) " +
                string.Format("SELECT NOW(), name, lname, score FROM {0} ", tablename) );
```

Your query is only a string and you have the value :)